# node.js selenium chrome headless one instance starts several 'chrome' processes

Tags: node.js, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-headless

Environment Ubuntu 18.x Server running node.js with selenium and chrome.

Why does this basic code with one webdriver and one chrome headless instance create total of 7 processes of 'chrome' (only one chromedriver process)

5 of these 'chrome' processes are using 40MB to 70MB of RAM each while doing nothing at startup. and two 'chrome' processes are using 10MB RAM.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var myLib = require('../MyCommonLibraries/myLibrary.js');

var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),
chrome    = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome'),
By = webdriver.By,
until = webdriver.until;

var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
.forBrowser('chrome')
.setChromeOptions(new chrome.Options().addArguments('--headless'))
.build();


var appPort = 12791;






var httpServer = app.listen(appPort, function(){

   let appStartTime = myLib.getDateTimeInET();
   console.log( "         -------------  " + appStartTime + " -------------------");
   console.log( '                 Server listening on port ' + appPort +  "\n\n");

});
```

Is there anything I can do to limit the number of processes this runs ?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. It is normal behavior for chrome to open a separate proceeses instead of one resource heavy process.

I came across several links talking about it.

https://www.howtogeek.com/124218/why-does-chrome-have-so-many-open-processes/

https://superuser.com/questions/461552/why-are-there-multiple-chrome-instances-running-even-though-i-only-have-one-wind